# How to set up Java and Scala in one single Module in Intellij IDEA 11?

Tags: java, scala, maven, compiler-construction, intellij-idea

I have got IntelliJ 11. I use Maven for dependency management.

I want to create one module which contains Java and Scala source files. I have already added a folder "src/main/java" and "src/main/scala" under Project Settings => Module  => "Module XYZ". The Scala facet is also added already.

What do I need to make IntelliJ compile both correctly?

Comment: What is happening incorrectly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did not find a good Google result first. Got it working now. This site explains it very clearly:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290032

Answer (score 2):

**To create a new project that uses Scala:**

1. In "New Project" wizard check "Scala" in technologies list.
2. Provide a path to Scala installation (if not detected)

**To add a new module that uses Scala into existing project:**

1. In "Add Module" wizard check "Scala" in technologies list.
2. Provide a path to Scala installation (if not detected)

**To add Scala support to existing module:**

1. Right-click the module in Project View, choose "Add Framework Support..."
2. Check "Scala" in technologies list (unavailable if module has Scala facet attached)
3. Provide a path to Scala installation (if not detected)

**To manually configure existing module:**

1. Create library "scala-compiler":

   - Classes:

     - scala-compiler.jar
     - scala-library.jar
2. Create library "scala-library":

   - Classes:

     - scala-dbc.jar
     - scala-library.jar
     - scala-swing.jar
   - Sources:

     - scala-dbc-src.jar
     - library-src.jar
     - swing-src.jar

**Docs:**
/doc/scala-devel-docs/api/

(if you downloaded Scala as an archive, you need to get separate API docs archive and extract it so that \doc\scala-devel-docs\api exist; if you installed Scala using LzPack, then API docs are already there)

3. Add Scala facet to the module, select "scala-compiler" library as compiler library
4. Add "scala-library" to module dependencies.

**Hints:**

- Don't add Scala compiler library to module dependencies (unless you really need Scala compiler classes in your code)
- Remember to attach "scala-library*.jar" to Scala compiler library, it's a dependency of "scala-compiler*.jar" itself.

Source: [Project-configuration-explained](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206001829-Project-configuration-explained)