# How to add scala-library.jar to bootclasspath

Tags: scala, maven, build

I have mixed scala java project (maven) .I go this bunch of errors . I searched some forums and saw that I need to add the scala-library.jar to the bootclasspath. however since I'm newbie, I do not know how to that . I will be very grateful if some one can guide me step by step here .
I am using intellij. linux

this is the errors that i'm getting :

[scalac] java.lang.Error: typeConstructor inapplicable for 
   [scalac]     at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:35)
   [scalac]     at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.typeConstructor(Symbols.scala:868)
   [scalac]     at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$Definitions$definitions$$booltype(Definitions.scala:157)
   [scalac]     at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scala:797)
   [scalac]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.(Global.scala:678)
... (and more....)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: [Working In Scala with both IntelliJ and Maven](http://patterngazer.blogspot.co.at/2011/04/working-in-scala-with-both-intellij-and.html)? You should use version 2.10 for the scala-library version.

Also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325792/how-to-set-up-java-and-scala-in-one-single-module-in-intellij-idea-11) (linking to [devnet.jetbrains.net](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290032))

---

**EDIT**: You need to be more specific how you do your setup and if IntelliJ is involved or not.

I can do the following without problem:

- installed Maven is 3.0.3
- copy example `pom.xml` from http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html
- replace `scala-library` version by `2.10.0` and `maven-compiler-plugin` version by `3.0`
- put test code in `src/main/java` and `src/main/scala`
- run `mvn compile` from the terminal

Works.

Comment: no, it doesn't help . still don't know how to add scala-library.jar to bootclasspath .

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a maven expert, but since the error you are getting is when you run the _compiler_, it means your general project setup is flawed. Have you tried creating a project from scratch following any of the above links? Are you building from within IDEA or directly Maven? Which Scala version are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I followed the steps here http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290032 (add scala support ) and it worked , I also had to add some dependencies . and it works